# Compatible OS on AMD APU Dual Core-E1-2100 with 2Gb RAM

Tags: 12.04

I would like to use Ubuntu on my Lenovo laptop with AMD APU Dual Core-E1-2100 and 2Gb RAM, let me know the compatible Ubuntu OS.

Comment: For Hardware support visit: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install the latest version of Ubuntu (14.04) 64bit version.

You can download it from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/)